# Can a user access data from a context_dict?

Tags: python, django-templates

My `models.py`:

```
class Mymodel(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    other_useful_field = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    ...
    secret_field = models.CharField(max_length=32)
```

My `views.py`:

```
def myview(request):
    context_dict=[]
    context=Mymodel.objects.get(id=1)
    context_dict=['reserved_data'] = context
    return render(request, 'mytemplate.html', context_dict)
```

My `mytemplate.html`:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% load staticfiles %}

{% block title %}{{ reserved_data.title }}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}Hello world{% endblock %}
```

Is there a (simple*) method for a user to read all 'reserved_data'?

Can a user have access to secret_field?

I don't want that to happen.

*simple, I mean a good hacker eventually can have access to all data anyway...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template is rendered on the server and output as HTML for the user to see. The user never sees the raw template. As long as your server is secure you have nothing to worry about.